# Why should I use cookies other than for storing a session id?

Tags: session, cookies, session-cookies, web-container, servlet-container

For HTTP as far as I understand are two ways to store data belonging to a client and bring some kind of state into a otherwise stateless Browser-webcontainer-connection: 1) Data stored in cookies on the client-side - or 2) A session ID stored in a cookie and the associated data stored in a webcontainer on the server-side. When I compare these two possibilities I can't come up with a reason, why one should go the first way. But still, when I look at my browser's cookies, I see a lot of data stored in them.

- A webcontainer (like tomcat) can store arbitrary data together with a session id - A cookie is quite limited in size.
- Cookies are more vulnerable, since they are stored on the client's side. Keep data on the server-side is, as it looks for me, just more secure.
- Both, cookies and webcontainer-sessions, can define expiration dates.
- Both, browser and webcontainer, persist their data over restarts.

Can anyone come up with a scenario where the use of cookies for storing session data has benefits or is even necessary?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with relying solely on session is that in order to limit the server's memory usage, the session data has to be purged after some time, for example [20 minutes is the default of ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Thus, if the users of your site have to log in and you want to give them an option of "remember me", your users will be logged out after a period of inactivity if you use the session for that purpose.

The simplest way to implement this would be to store an encrypted cookie with a distant expiration date, which would let the user authenticate at later times.

Having written that, in order to allow users to end their sessions remotely, sites like [Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8154?hl=en) and [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-security/forget-to-log-out-help-is-on-the-way/425136200765) don't rely solely on a cookie value for authentication, but they are probably using a special store for those sessions and not general purpose session.